# How to fill fields in a webview gettings data from remote URL

Tags: android, webview

I am new developer in Android, I would to like to fill fields in a web view getting page from remote URL.
My application used shared preferences to store username/password to fill automatically fields username/password belongs to a login page. This login page is retrieved from a remote url and dispayed in webview.

How to fill the fields username/password?
Any suggestion can help me.
I already used javascript and does not work.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
"document.getElementById('username').value = '"+username +"';" +
"document.getElementById('password').value = '"+password+"';" +
"var frms = document.getElementsByName('loginForm');};");
```